# Why is an array parameter shared by the recursive stack?

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a program that finds a hamiltonian path in a maze using backtracking. It should return the path on the maze encoded in numbers. The problem is when a stack falls back, one of the variables(which is the representation of the maze) gets inherited from the call, while the others even if they were declared the same way, don't(which is fine). I tried a couple of workarounds including instantiation by making a separate class and I included debug messages. Here's the code with some comments to help.

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    //I made a separate class for the function
    class btr
    {
        public short[,] mz = new short[,] { };//tried to pull the variable out of the function, no success 
        public void bt(int i, int j, int l)
        {
            bool ok;
            ok = true;
            Console.WriteLine("in" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l) + 'i' + i + 'j' + j + '\n'); //debug message for entering
            if (i > 0 && mz[i - 1, j] == 0)
            {
                ok = false;
                mz[i, j] = 1; // 1 aka go up
                var x = new btr { };
                //my attempt to avoid the problem by instantiating the function, no success...
                x.mz = mz;
                x.bt(i - 1, j, l);
                //When this function exits the mz variable is copied to this one. Same for all the ifs below
            }
            if (j > 0 && mz[i, j - 1] == 0)
            {
                ok = false;
                mz[i, j] = 2; //2 aka go left
                var x = new btr { };
                x.mz = mz;
                x.bt(i, j - 1, l);
            }
            if (i < l && mz[i + 1, j] == 0)
            {
                ok = false;
                mz[i, j] = 3;//3 aka go down 
                var x = new btr { };
                x.mz = mz;
                x.bt(i + 1, j, l);
            }
            if (j < l && mz[i, j + 1] == 0)
            {
                ok = false;
                mz[i, j] = 4;//4 aka go right 
                var x = new btr { };
                x.mz = mz;
                x.bt(i, j + 1, l);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("out" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l) + 'i' + i + 'j' + j + '\n');  //debug message for exiting
            if (ok) //this is for printing the solution when it is found
            {
                mz[i, j] = 8;// 8 aka the end
                foreach (int x in mz)
                {
                    if (x == 0) { ok = false; break; }
                }
                if (ok)
                    Console.WriteLine("result" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l));
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {//this is just for preparing the first call 

    static short[,] test = new short[2, 2] { { 0, 0}, { 0, 0} };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x= new btr { };
        x.mz = test;
        x.bt(0,0,1);
    }
    public static string print(short[,] vr,int l)//casts my array into a string that can be printed
    {
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= l; j++)
            {
                s += vr[i,j];
            }
            s += '\n';
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

}

I gave as a test a 2x2 maze without any obstacles(represented by test declared all 0s) and it should output 2 solutions, it outputs only one and the solution gets "injected" into the stack. here's the output:

```
in
00
00
i0j0

in
30
00
i1j0

in
30
40
i1j1

in
30
41
i0j1

out
30
41
i0j1

result
38
41

out
38
41
i1j1

out
38
41
i1j0

out
38
41
i0j0
```

As you can see when the function exits the maze remains 38 41 instead of gradually falling back to 00 00 so more solutions could be computed. i and j is not affected.

Comment: You're mutating the same array instance.

Comment: Recursive and immutable are great for these kind of algorithms, they make reasoning out everything so much easier. The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that you are using an (mutable) array. You either use an immutable type that can't change or you make fresh copies of the array every time you hand it down to a new recursive call.

Comment: So how can I make a new instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual cause was the fact that an array is not a value type so it is passed by reference, which points to the same instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

The reason why variables i and j were not affected is that they are value types, therefore they are passed by value.

So there are 2 solutions: clone the field after each call(slow) or return it to the original state upon exiting(not possible in all scenarios, but in this one it is)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that immutability is a useful technique when dealing with recursion, especially where back-tracking is needed. That said, it can create unnecessary overhead when dealing with arrays, especially if they are large.

In your scenario, because you know what element of the array you are modifying before you make your recursive call, you can simply reset the value after the recursive call returns. In a sense, you are taking advantage of the call stack to preserve state — in this case, the `i` and `j` of the array element that was modified — and using that to restore the state after the recursive call.

That will look something like this:

```
public void bt(int i, int j, int l)
{
    bool ok;
    ok = true;
    Console.WriteLine("in" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l) + 'i' + i + 'j' + j + '\n'); //debug message for entering
    if (i > 0 && mz[i - 1, j] == 0)
    {
        ok = false;
        mz[i, j] = 1; // 1 aka go up
        bt(i - 1, j, l);
        mz[i, j] = 0;
        //When this function exits the mz variable is copied to this one. Same for all the ifs below
    }
    if (j > 0 && mz[i, j - 1] == 0)
    {
        ok = false;
        mz[i, j] = 2; //2 aka go left
        bt(i, j - 1, l);
        mz[i, j] = 0;
    }
    if (i < l && mz[i + 1, j] == 0)
    {
        ok = false;
        mz[i, j] = 3;//3 aka go down 
        bt(i + 1, j, l);
        mz[i, j] = 0;
    }
    if (j < l && mz[i, j + 1] == 0)
    {
        ok = false;
        mz[i, j] = 4;//4 aka go right 
        bt(i, j + 1, l);
        mz[i, j] = 0;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("out" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l) + 'i' + i + 'j' + j + '\n');  //debug message for exiting
    if (ok) //this is for printing the solution when it is found
    {
        mz[i, j] = 8;// 8 aka the end
        foreach (int x in mz)
        {
            if (x == 0) { ok = false; break; }
        }
        if (ok)
            Console.WriteLine("result" + '\n' + Program.print(mz, l));
    }
}
```

Note the `mz[i, j] = 0;` after each call.

If you like, you can even put the `mz` variable back into the method parameter list. You're only ever dealing with a single instance of the array, so it doesn't matter much whether you keep that as a class field or a method parameter.

Comment: This is a good solution, however I was looking for one that stops the actual sharing of the variable because I'm afraid I will deal with something like this in the future.

Comment: You can always make a copy of the array and pass that when calling. There are many ways to copy an array, but one of the easiest is to just use the `ToArray()` extension method. E.g. `bt(i - 1, j, l, mz.ToArray());` (assuming, of course, you put the array parameter back in the method's parameter list). That said, each recursive scenario is different: when dealing with value types, you don't need to worry about copies; when dealing with reference types (like arrays) that you intend to change, you'll always either need to make a copy or undo the modification after the recursive call returns.

Comment: The best thing to do is, instead of trying to follow one specific pattern always, to understand the nature of recursion and the need to be careful about state of variables and objects between calls. In that way, you'll be able to correctly select the right implementation for each specific scenario. IMHO, when dealing with arrays where you are modifying only a single element, it's better to do it as above, i.e. don't make a copy, just return the value to its original value after the call.